# How to move Magento Admin notification to header?

Tags: php, magento, templates, layout

I would like to move the notification toolbar thats located under the menu of Magento's admin panel and place it in a div i have in the header.

I tried achieving this by cutting the following line from app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('notifications'); ?>
```

and pasting it in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/header.phtml

but that didn't work.

could someone advise me on how to move the notification block to the header section, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('notifications'); ?>
```

place above code under below code

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
```